# How to determine a distribution based on a formula?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

**Prompt**.
Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n, Y$ be iid with $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ RV's and $\overline{X} = \frac1n \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i$ , $S_n^2 = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i = 1}^{n}(X_i - \overline{X})^2$. Specify the distribution $\sqrt{\frac{n-1}{n+1}} \frac {Y - \overline{X}}{S_n}$ .

**Solution**. So I've looked through different textbooks, and there are several questions. I'm assuming $Y \epsilon X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ and the right hand side of the mystery distribution is the normal or t-distribution. I'm assuming its the t-distribution or some perverted variant. Is it okay to say that? How do you prove something like this?

Comment: The normal distribution is *not* the $t$-distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Comment / Hints:* I would 'pick it apart', step by step.

Maybe a useful point of view is that you get the $X_i$ first, and
find the sample $\bar X$ and variance $S_x^2$ of these $n$ observations.

What are the distributions of $\bar X$ and of $(n-1)S_x^2/\sigma^2$?
Now add the 'new' observation $Y$ to the mix: What is the distribution
of $Y - \bar X.$

To follow up on your 't-distribution' hunch: What is the definition of Student's t distribution in terms of
normal and chi-squared distributions. (Depending on your definition of 'perversion', probably best to steer away from that.)

*Note:* If you want to use this problem to learn something, I suggest you try
this approach before someone else uses it and posts a complete Answer. (Seems to be an important problem leading to a 'prediction interval' for an extra observation.)

Comment: Thanks for the info! I assumed its the t-distribution since there are n+1 observations, and i'm assuming n is the sample. Since the right hand side looks awfully similar to the normal. Again thank you for leading me to the right answer!

Comment: The number of observations has to do with the df of the t distribution. Wishing you success.